# How to compare list A and list B containing integers and print the missing integers?

Tags: python, list

I wish to print the values that are missing by comparing A and B lists.

For example, when I `print(a)` it will show me that `[1,2,5,7,8,9,11,12]` are missing and different from A.

```
A = ['0', '0', '3', '4', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '10', '10', '10']

B = ['1', '10', '2', '5', '0', '3', '4', '7', '8', '9', '6', '11', '12']
```

I tried this but it wont work.

```
a = []
for x in A:
    for y in B:
        if y != u:
            a.append(y)
```

Is there an easy way to do so? I have been trying to learn more now. Hopefully, someone could help.

Comment: `sorted(map(int, set(B) - set(A)))`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use set difference:

```
>>> A = ['0', '0', '3', '4', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '10', '10', '10']
>>> B = ['1', '10', '2', '5', '0', '3', '4', '7', '8', '9', '6', '11', '12']
>>> set(B)-set(A)
{'5', '9', '7', '2', '12', '11', '8', '1'}
```

Comment: then add a list() to turn back to list if you need list properties. `list(set(B)-set(A))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an if statement:

```
for elt in B:
    if elt not in A:
        print(elt)
```

edit : probably less effective than the option using sets above. But I'll let it there so you can learn about the "not in" operator in for loops ;)

Comment: Thank you sir. Have completed.

Answer (score 1):

A counter solution also works -

```
from collections import Counter
C = Counter()
A = ['0', '0', '3', '4', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '10', '10', '10']
B = ['1', '10', '2', '5', '0', '3', '4', '7', '8', '9', '6', '11', '12']
C.update(A)
C.update(B)
D = [k for k, v in C.iteritems() if v == 1]
# OP ['11', '12', '1', '2', '5', '7', '9', '8']
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, have completed.